# Usefulness of unsigned char in on embedded systems in C

Tags: c, resources, embedded, memory-footprint

I'm working on a Chip-8 emulator in C with the goal of having it be as cross platform and as small as possible for compatibility with embedded systems and systems with low specs (and to challenge myself), which means being able to use SDL, ncurses (when I get to that point) and something else as well. As such, I've been using unsigned chars in place of ints or unsigned ints, and I used "typedef unsigned char byte" to make it more convenient. Am I wasting my time, even with the goal of ideally making it compatible with very small systems, or would just using "typedef unsigned int byte" be enough without sacrificing performance?

Comment: I don't know about Chip-8, but googling I read that is 8 bit. Supposing that the int type has size of one byte and char too, is indifferent to use `typedef unsigned int` or `typedef unsigned char`. They have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, Chip-8 is an 8 bit language, but my concern was less with the interpreter/emulator itself and more with the host system. 
So then the size of int will change with the system it's compiled on/for?

Comment: try printing out sizeof(int).  it may very well be 1 byte for that compiler for that target, that is kind of the idea of the int variable type, it varies depending on the target (moreso than char or long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just separate the interpreter from the io bindings.

Only the interpreter needs to be 8 bits portable.

Each target platforms will have a different set of technologies available for IO.

SDL or curses will give you some sort of portability between *nix and windows platforms but if available, you'll probably have 32bits integers, maybe have to deal with 16 bits. But surely not with 8 bit integers.

On the other hand, dealing with 8 bits and 16 bits bare metal processors, means you'll probably just hook your project directly to the graphic driver.

Comment: It uses 8-bits mostly for dealing specifically with the instruction set itself. So then should I only use or deal with 8 bit integers with the instruction set/cpu struct and regular unsigned ints for everything else?

Comment: Yes, unless you have an specific 8 bit target. Everything alive is at least 32 bits, except some popular pic and avr 16bit controllers that cost the same as their 32bit evolutions.

Comment: Ideally, I want it to be compatible with every system humanly possible. Again, for the challenge, which is why I initially started with 8-bit integers, and why I included the possibility of ncurses as an alternative to SDL

Comment: curses is no alternative to  `every system humanly possible` but is enough to `almost every *nix system ever`. If you're doing it for the challenge, download a PDP-11 emulator and make your code work there. ( You'll face some C portability issues though as you'll probably deal with pre standardised  compilers).

Comment: I'll add another graphics alternative when necessary, ncurses was just the first thing that came to mind. And I didn't think about PDP-11 mainframes. At one point, I had a telnet account on the Living Computer Museum's mainframes, but an emulator would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the basic idea right, but not the solution. In modern C, we have the `uint_fast8_t` type in stdint.h.

This is the type you should use, meaning that you are telling the compiler: "I don't need more than 8 bytes for this integer, but feel free to use a larger size if that improves performance."

Comment: But wouldn't that cause comparability issues when building to something like DOS?

Comment: @Josh Why would you build for DOS? No it won't cause any compatibility issues at all, that's the beauty of the stdint types. Although, since you don't know quite how large the integer is, you have to treat it like `uint8_t` when considering implicit type promotions.